# how to form create methods to save the data to the database using django rest framework

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to save the data from the `JSON` file to the Database using the Deserialization the serializers in Django using the drf and these are my models:

```
    from django.db import models

    class elements(models.Model):
       id=models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
       slug=models.CharField(max_length=100)
       name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
       courseType=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
       return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.id, self.slug,self.name,   self.courseType)
    class types(models.Model):
       elements=models.ForeignKey(elements, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and the serializer files are as follows:

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from serial.models import elements,types
    class elementserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
        model = elements
        field=('id','name','slug','courseType')
    class courseserial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      elements=elementserializer(many=True)
      class Meta:
        model = types
        field=('elements')
```

the create methods that I use keeps giving errors even when I tried using the documentation http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers can anyone tell me a better way to write the create methods to save the data to the database using the serializers. The create method that I use is as follows:

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        elements_data = validated_data.pop('elements')
        types = types.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for elements_data in elements_data:
           elements.objects.create(types=types, **elements_data)     
        return types
```